# Display colored images in greyscale on web page

Tags: php, javascript, image-manipulation

How can I convert images on my website into greyscale? I don't care if it's PHP or JS, but I think PHP is nicer.

In particular I have a blog with various posts containing images, and I want the thumbnail images that preview the blog post on the index page to be greyscale while the represented images in the blog post stay colored. These thumbnail images share a class called `.post-thumbnail` there the `img` tag is inside the element with that class.

All I want is something that *would* look like this in CSS is there would be that property:

```
.post-thumbnail img { image-transform: greyscale; }
```

In PHP or JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick search on StackOverflow finds this:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('dave.png');
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagepng($im, 'dave.png');
```

See [Making an Image Greyscale with GD Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276780/making-an-image-greyscale-with-gd-library)

Comment: Not sure how that would end up where I want it. I am already trying several ways I found on Google and on Stackoverflow but every single one of them seems either extremely complicated or bloated or very old-fashioned. Why is something so simple so hard?

Comment: Okay, I am trying to use pixastic with jQuery. http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/#jquery
But that code doesn't produce the wanted result...

    <script type="text/javascript">
  var pixastic_parseonload = true;
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="h ttp://ajax.googleapis.com/../jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="pixastic.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(".attachment-post-thumbnail").pixastic("desaturate");

 </script>

Comment: "complicated or bloated or very old-fashioned". This three-line snippet looks neither complicated nor bloated. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: The script creates a new image on your server that is a greyscale version of the original image. You wanted to know how to convert images to greyscale with PHP. You want it in less than 3 lines?